# join table A first row with table B first row without common identifiers (for all rows) . Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I messed up with identifiers and my two tables can't be joined by any column. But their order is the same. First row in table A is first row in table B, second row in table A is second row in table B and the same with rest. Is there any way to join those two tables by their row number or something like that?

For example:

Table A:

```
two
three
one
```

Table B:

```
cat
dog
mouse
```

Expected result would be:

```
two - cat
three - dog
one - mouse
```

Or is it not possible and I need to start everything all over again ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say " their order is the same"? Do you mean the order in which rows were inserted into the tables?

Comment: Whilst there are ways to query these by a pseudo row ID, I would recommend recreating the tables otherwise you're just delaying the inevitable when the rows are eventually not in sequence.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering of the rows in each table.

Comment: @DavidFaber yes, inserted order is the same.

Comment: @DazzKnowles I don't really want to recreate one of these tables, because it has relations with other tables. I am just migrating data from one table to another. I will be using newly created tables which have proper ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an auto increment column to each table:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD COLUMN (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD COLUMN (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then you can do a join

```
SELECT num, animal
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
```

Output:

```
num     animal  
two     cat
three   dog
one     mouse
```

Comment: Thats a great idea! How come I never thought of that. I will try it later and if it works the way I expect I will mark it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the query

```
select a.c1, b.c1
from
(select c1 ,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rn1 from taba,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r ) a
join
(select c1 ,@rownum1:=@rownum1+1 as rn2 from tabb,(SELECT @rownum1:=0) s ) b
on a.rn1 = b.rn2
```

SQL Fiddle :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a046b5/22

Comment: Without ORDER BY this query isn't stabile.. Because MySQL is free to return records in anny order without ORDER BY

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . That is a rather niggling point and should be addressed to the OP, not to this answer.  What the OP is asking for is not valid, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.